Why does Python add quotation marks when I add a space after comma in a string join?
Here's the code I use to just scrape a website for restaurants and the prices for them.
def collect_dishes_list():
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    restaurants = {}
    restaurant_sections = soup.find_all("div", class_="lunch--inner")
    
    for section in restaurant_sections:
        restaurant_name = section.find("h3").text.strip()
        dishes = []
    
        dish_items = section.find_all("div", class_="single-offer--content")
        price_items = section.find_all("div", class_="single-offer--price")
    
        for dish_item, price_item in zip(dish_items, price_items):
            dish_name = dish_item.find("p").text.strip()
            price = price_item.find("p").text.strip()
            name = f'{dish_name} :{price}'
            dishes.append(name)
    
        restaurants[restaurant_name] = dishes
    return restaurants

for restaurant, dishes in collect_dishes_list().items():
dict_to_send = {}

    dict_to_send[restaurant] = dishes
    
    yaml_string = yaml.dump(dict_to_send, allow_unicode=True)
    
    utf8_yaml_string = yaml_string.encode("utf-8")
    
    payload = {
        "text": utf8_yaml_string.decode()
    }
    
    print(payload)

The output is as such:
{'text': 'Restaurant_Name:\n- Dish_Name_1 :Price_1\n- Dish_Name_2 :Price_2\n'}

When I want to add a space after the colon like name = f'{dish_name} : {price}' then my output is getting wrapped in single quote marks such as
{'text': "Restaurant_Name:\n- 'Dish_Name_1 : Price_1'\n- 'Dish_Name_2 : Price_2'\n"}

Why does that happen? I would like to have spaces before And after colon
Have tried to use any other string join ways, none seems to solve the situation:
dishes.append(f"{dish_name} : {price}")
price = " " +  price_item.find("p").text.strip()
dishes.append(f"{dish_name} :{price}")

price = price_item.find("p").text.strip()
dishes.append(" : ".join([dish_name, price]))


Aside: all that UTF-8 encoding and decoding at the end appears to be entirely superfluous…!?

As far as I understood from the friend this was done because some Estonian letters are not appearing as supposed to.

@Scentryum: Assuming this is Python 3, yaml_string.encode("utf-8").decode() will verify the data is UTF-8 by encoding it (raising exceptions if that fails), then converting it back to the exact same string data. Only the encode is doing anything useful; you could just change it to yaml_string.encode() # Verify legal UTF-8, followed by payload = {"text": yaml_string}, avoiding storing utf8_yaml_string, and decoding it, because if the encode succeeds, then yaml_string is exactly the same as utf8_yaml_string.decode(), and you already have the former.

@ShadowRanger Encoding doesn’t “verify” anything. It’s taking characters, text, and expresses them in bytes. This always works with anything when encoding to UTF-8, since UTF-8 can encode everything.

@deceze: It can't actually. If there are UCS2/UTF-16 surrogate code points in the str, e.g. if the str is "\ud800\udc00" (I have no idea if that surrogate pair means anything, it's just an example), the str exists legally, but trying to encode it to UTF-8 will raise a UnicodeEncodeError. Yes, it's stupid and annoying, but it does mean the trial encode is not completely pointless in some specific cases (I highly doubt this is one of them, but it's possible), but the subsequent decode is definitely pointless.

@ShadowRanger Fair enough, then I just take umbrage at the phrasing "will verify the data is UTF-8". yaml_string isn't UTF-8, it's text. utf8_yaml_string will definitely be UTF-8, or not exist at all because an exception was raised.

@deceze: Ah, true. I should have said "will verify the data can be encoded to UTF-8", to avoid confusing encoded data (bytes produced by encodeing a str with a particular encoding) with platonic ideal of text (str).

The quotes are protecting the raw strings against being interpreted as single element dictionaries. You gave yaml.dump a dict mapping a string to a list of str, and, without the quotes, the space-separated strings would look like yaml dictionaries. To protect against that (so you get back a list of str, not a list of single-element dicts), yaml adds the quotes.
Removing the space removes the problem, because  Dish_Name_1 :Price_1 isn't how YAML represents a dict (there needs to be whitespace after the colon), so it's unambiguously just a string and no quoting is needed.

Thanks for the explanation, I'm not a Python guy, just helping out a friend. Any recommendations to fix this situation? At the end we send this yaml to slack, so it needs to be a yaml. I need to find a way to send without quotation marks

@Scentryum It's valid YAML as is. There's nothing wrong. Why do you think anything needs to change here?

We do not want to receive the data with quote marks is all.
Requirements:

Have space before AND after colon
Not wrapped with single quotation marks


@Scentryum Where does that "requirement" come from? If you want to express that text in YAML, then it must be quoted. ShadowRanger explained why. Any proper YAML parser will parse it back to the text you intended. Are you actually encountering any issues with this YAML, or are you just going by aesthetics?

@Scentryum: Is the goal to have it deserialize to one-element dicts, or to strings? As deceze (and myself) have said, with the space, and without the quotes, it doesn't round-trip to the same information; you'd be putting in strings, and getting out dicts. Unless this is some exercise to hand-write a YAML serializer and those strings should be dicts when deserialized, making it do what you want would mean you'd get the desired aesthetics at the expense of correct behavior.

@ShadowRanger The space is not generally necessary after a colon for a colon to be mapping value indicator. E.g. take {"abc":"xyz"}: that is valid JSON, so it is valid YAML  (although some parser don't properly handle that).

@Anthon: Entirely possible. For PyYAML's implementation (which I believe uses libyaml under the hood when available), the space matters. Note that the OP's strings don't have curly braces around the colon-separated pair so it's definitely not valid JSON (nor quotes around the "keys", which JS object literals allow you to omit, but strict JSON requires them), which may make the spaces relevant to the more space-sensitive YAML format once JSON compatibility no longer matters. I don't know/care, point is, the OP's approach, with PyYAML, needs no space, or quotes to avoid dict interpretation.

@ShadowRanger You're right, I missed that he is using PyYAML (from the allow_unicode parameter), and that does only support a subset of the outdated YAML 1.1 specification. JSON compatibility was introduced with YAML 1.2 in 2009.
